# gremlin.net with Cosmos DB: RequestRateTooLarge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin

I get RequestRateTooLarge exception when doing queries that involve around 60 vertices. The problem seems to be related to the number of vertices and edges involved in the query (it does not happen with "smaller" queries). Increasing the throughput does not solve the problem, it just happens less frequently.

Would it be useful to wait some time between retrievals of the results of the query? I.e. doing a Thread.Sleep() between calls to something like query.ExecuteNextAsync() of Graph API. I could not find an equivalent in gremlin.net so I haven't tried yet.

If this is not a solution, what can I do?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Regarding the throughput I expressed badly, I meant that I am trying to keep it as low as possible, however just increasing it does not seem a general solution for the problem, it just makes it happen less frequently.

[Cosmos documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#RequestRateTooLarge) says that the RequestRateTooLarge response has a header x-ms-retry-after-ms that tells how long to wait before the next request, but how can I get this value from the exception?

Comment: This is the exception: https://pastebin.com/2QN9tHNQ .
Its InnerException is null.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a wait period will address the RequestRateTooLarge exception you are experiencing.

**Another option** is to increase the reserved throughput for the container. You can find additional information about exceeding the reserved throughput exception [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#RequestRateTooLarge).

Comment: An arbitrary wait period isn't going to help, as there can always be a case where the RU deficit will push the next query beyond the wait. And the OP already stated that the 400RU limit is a project requirement (though that doesn't really make much sense).

Comment: Agree! Best bet is to plan accordingly. Azure Cosmos DB Capacity Planner Tool: https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner